# stop the reloading in collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, nsarray, uicollectionviewcell

I new to objective-c.I am working on collection view.In my collection view,I have list of data in my array.When I load the data from my array into collection cell,It is not showing as per array order.the cell value is changing continuously when I am scrolling.

here is my code.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return myObject.count;
}

- (UIView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if([statusfield isEqualToString:@"13"])
{
    [cell.mySegmentedControl setTitle:@"SEND TO ADMIN" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [cell.mySegmentedControl setTitle:@"EVALUATE" forSegmentAtIndex:1];
}
else if([statusfield isEqualToString:@"5"])
{
    [cell.mySegmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [cell.mySegmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:1];
}

else if([statusfield  isEqualToString: @"1"])
{
    [cell.mySegmentedControl setTitle:@"ACCEPT" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [cell.mySegmentedControl setTitle:@"REJECT" forSegmentAtIndex:1];
}
else if([statusfield isEqualToString:@"3"])
{
    [cell.mySegmentedControl setTitle:@"VIEW" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [cell.mySegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];
}
return cell;
}
```

The segmented control value is updating based on the array.When I scroll the collection view the order of the is changing.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: it is happen because of re-usability of cell . you can managed it using Model class.

Comment: can you give a example or sample program for my scenario...

Answer (score 1):

Check below code. It may help you

```
for (UIImageView *imgView in cell.subviews) {
    if ([imgView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        [imgView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

After that add your view

```
UIImageView *segmentImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, cell.frame.size.width - 10, cell.frame.size.height - 10)];
segmentImageView.image = [segmentControlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
segmentImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[cell addSubview:segmentImageView];
```